# How can I get innerhtml except one of its child Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to print my elements so I need to get innerHtml of the whole div but I need to hide one element from printed but still found in the main page

My attempt looks like this

```
var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML
             +" <div class='row'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-tasks'></span><b></b></div>"
             + document.getElementById(tble).innerHTML
             + document.getElementById(img).innerHTML;
```

this works fine but I need to hide the elment ID ="attach"

```
var panel = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
var filteredpanel = panel.remove(document.getElementById("attach").innerHTML)
```

Comment: Hide the element `#attach` first, then assign `printcontent`, then show `#attach` again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#attach').hide(); /* hide */
var printcontent = $(el).html() /* assign var */
             +" <div class='row'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-tasks'></span><b></b></div>"
             + $(tble).html()
             + $(img).html();
$('#attach').show(); /* show again */
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#divID').not('#attach');
```

or

```
$('#divID:not(#attach)');
```

Comment: `var filteredpanel = $('#panelPrint:not(#attach)'); `  >> ` var printcontent = filteredpanel.innerHTML` it gives me undefined @hya

Comment: try `$('#panelPrint:not(#attach)').html()` instead of mixing vanilla and jQuery

Comment: @DarrenSweeney It gives no error but still show the #attach

Comment: @saraadly try this:

`var copy = $('#id').clone();
copy.children('#b').remove();
var panel = copy.html();`